# Designtime scope in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-component, visualdesigner

I have a question about how to setup components in a winforms application so they can interact with each other. But I want to use the visual designer to set this up.

What I have is a component called myDataBase and a component called myDataTable.
Now the component myDataTable has a property of type myDataBase.
So in code I can do

```
myDataBase db = new myDataBase();
myDataTable dt = new myDataTable();
dt.DataBase = db;
```

The property DataBase in component myDataTable is public, so I can also use the visual designer to assign the DataBase property.

[image]

Now for my problem.
I have many many forms that have one or more components of myDataTable on it.
I only want one instance for myDataBase.

What I do now is I create a component myDataBase dbMain = new myDataBase() on the mainform.
On every form I have to set the property for all myDataTable components to this dbMain.
I have to do this in code because the visual designer cannot see the dbMain component on the  mainform.

So the question is, can I create one instance of component myDataBase that is visible to the visual designer on all forms, so I can use the visual designer to set the property of myDataTable components ?

For those that now Delphi, I want something like the DataModule in Delphi.

Answer (score 1):

You can't without some code.

The easiest thing you can do, as far as I am concerned, it to create a base form, deriving from `Form`, and in that form, you make a property pointing to a singleton instance of your database object. You can bind to that property, and still keep it as simple as possible.

You just need to make *your* form derive from this one:

```
public class DatasourceForm : Form
{
    public myDataBase DataBase
    {
        get
        {
            return myDataBaseFactory.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

And the factory in charge of creating the singleton database instance:

```
public class myDataBaseFactory
{
    private static readonly Lazy<myDataBase> lazy =
    new Lazy<myDataBase>(() => new myDataBase());

    public static myDataBase Current { get { return lazy.Value; } }
}
```

(Singleton implementation from [here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx))

Comment: Personally, I prefer [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for creating singletons ;-)

Comment: @UweKeim: Okay :) I do too actually.

Comment: All my forms are descendants of a baseform so I can easily implement this. But will the visual designer be able to see the property myDataBase on the inherited forms ?

Comment: I just tried this and the problem remains that the visual designer on an inherited form cannot see this property so I still have to do everything in code.

Comment: @GuidoG: You could add a [`BindingSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance that points to `this`. In that way you can bind to the property. Not sure if it is possible to add that on the base form.

Comment: That only solves part of the problem. I already have a bindingsource on my baseform and its DataBase property is set in the constructor. But there are lots of forms that need addidional bindingsources and myDataTables and what I wanted to do is set the DataBase property of these myDataTables using the visual designer and there the problem will remain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76867/discussion-between-patrick-hofman-and-guidog).